# I want the corresponding ID of last record in MS Access to appear inside a Message Box

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

Am working with Access as Database in C# (Visual Studio 15). I want to save form entries (add record) into the Access Database and would want the corresponding ID of the record to show in MsgBox upon a successful saving. I have tried the following:

```
 private void Form21_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          try
          {
              connection.Open();
              checkConnection.Text = "Server Connection, Successful";
              connection.Close();
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Error, Server not connected " + ex);
          }
      }
    

    private void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "insert into Students_File ([YourNames],[Nationality],[StateOfOrigin],[PlaceOfBirth],[DoB],[HomeAddress],[LastSchools1],[LastClass1],[LastSchools2],[LastClass2],[LastSchools3],[LastClass3],[AdmClass],[CurrentClass],[Guidian],[GuardianContact],[UserName],[PassWord],[Gender],[RegistrationDate]) values('" + YourNames.Text + "','" + Nationality.Text + "','" + StateOfOrigin.Text + "','" + PlaceOfBirth.Text + "','" + DoB.Text + "','" + HomeAddress.Text + "','" + LastSchools1.Text + "','" + LastClass1.Text + "','" + LastSchools2.Text + "','" + LastClass2.Text + "','" + LastSchools3.Text + "','" + LastClass3.Text + "','" + AdmClass.Text + "','" + CurrentClass.Text + "','" + Guidian.Text + "','" + GuardianContact.Text + "','" + UserName.Text + "','" + PassWord.Text + "','" + Gender.Text + "','" + RegistrationDate.Text + "')";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //MessageBox.Show("Congrats! Your registration, is successful. You may now click close button, then proceed to login");

        command.CommandText = "Select * from Students_File where UserName='" + UserName.Text + "' and PassWord='" + PassWord.Text + "'";
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Congrats! Your registration, is successful. You may now click close button, then proceed to login");
            this.Close();
        }
        else if (count > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the chosen username or password is currently existing or picked by another user. Consequently, your registration was not successful. Do please, decide another but a unique one. Thank you");
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: It does not answer my question. I needed the ID to appear in MessageBox if the new record addition was successful!

Comment: I figured if you could get the id then you could do whatever you needed to do with it after.

Comment: Sorry please, how do i manipulate the answer in the given link to my code above. I guess that's my weakness.

Comment: Why would user need to see record ID? Does it have any meaning to them?

Comment: While it will serve as student-id to the account owner, it will also be required in the forget password form to recover forgotten login details.

Comment: Concatenate ID variable into message string: `"...registration of " + ID + " is ..."`

Comment: May i have the full code view, please?

Comment: I don't see need for me to replicate your post. You already have code there. Just have your data validation code follow the INSERT code and modify the message box code. Actually, probably should put the INSERT action inside the If data validation.

Comment: I really don't need you replicate code but the main part regarding having the ID appear in messagebox...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229109/discussion-between-june7-and-wilfred).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
using (OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand("", conn))
{
    Command.CommandText = "Your big ugly mess - need to change this to parmaters!)";
    Command.Connection.Open();
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Command.CommandText = "Select @@Identity";
    var intLastID = Command.ExecuteScalar;

    MsgBox("Last id into database = " + intLastID);
}
```

As noted, you do want to change that insert command - it too long, too difficult to maintain, and subject to mistakes in code and even sql injection.

But, for now, you can use the above approach to get/pick up the last ID insert.

Comment: Thank you. This solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

In solution to my inquiry, i have the following code (From Kevin):

```
     string query = "Insert Into Categories (CategoryName) Values (?)";
        string query2 = "Select @@Identity";
        int ID;
        string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Northwind.mdb";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))

            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryName", OleDbType.Integer);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.CommandText = query2;
                ID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
```

Now, my challenge is how do i get the ID to appear in messagebox after a successful record creation. Please consider my earliest code in this post in connection with this.